# Error on optional field when using Core Service SynchronizeWithSchemaAndUpdate

Tags: core-service, schema-synchronization

I am trying to synchronize Components on a Schema that has a multi-value optional field "AAA" of type Embedded Schema "Aaa", which has a mandatory embedded text field "BBB" and another optional embedded field "CCC".

```
AAA - optional multi-value field on Embedded Schema 'Aaa'
 +-> BBB - mandatory single-value text field
 +-> CCC - optional single-value text field
```

When I create Components on my Schema, I don't have to enter any value for field AAA, and nothing appears in the Component XML. When I save the same Component in the CME, it saves successfully.

I have a Core Service client that executes `Client.SynchronizeWithSchemaAndUpdate(tcmUri, SynchronizeOptions)`, where Client is an `ICoreService` object using basicHttp binding, tcmUri is the TCMURI of the Component and SynchronizeOptions is `new SynchronizeOptions { SynchronizeFlags = SynchronizeFlags.All };`

The code above yields a `FaultException<CoreServiceFault>` whose message reads:

```
{"XML validation error. Reason: The element 'AAA' in namespace 'Aaa' has incomplete
content. List of possible elements expected: 'BBB' in namespace 'Aaa'."}
```

It doesn't make sense why I receive this error. Field AAA is optional multi-value. Only embedded field BBB is mandatory and this error should only be thrown if optional embedded field CCC has a value and mandatory field BBB has been omitted.

So my questions are: what is going on? is this a bug? has anybody seen this error before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately some of the flags are "destructive", meaning they can turn perfectly valid XML into invalid XML. The following flags should be safe:

```
SynchronizeFlags.ApplyDefaultValuesForMissingMandatoryFields |
SynchronizeFlags.Basic |
SynchronizeFlags.ConvertFieldType |
SynchronizeFlags.FixNamespace |
SynchronizeFlags.RemoveAdditionalValues |
SynchronizeFlags.RemoveUnknownFields;
```

The following flags can convert valid xml into invalid xml:

```
SynchronizeFlags.ApplyDefaultValuesForMissingNonMandatoryFields
SynchronizeFlags.ApplyFilterXsltToXhtmlFields
```

Hopefully we will get a less suicidal alternative to using "All" in a future releases, but it did unfortunately not make it into the SDL Web 8 release.

Comment: Indeed it works. There is no exception thrown when `SynchronizeFlags.ApplyDefaultValuesForMissingNonMandatoryFields` is missing. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

I have tried and tested the above scenario just now and I can see the component synchronization happening successfully. I further tried couple of more scenarios in the embedded schema and schema fields and all seems to be working fine. So to answer your question - This is not a bug in the API.

Just to get more knowledge, can you double check or may be triple check, you are passing the `SynchronizeFlags.All` flag while synchronizing. Also, is there anything else in the log apart from the above error?

Comment: I tried my code in 3 different systems and I have the error in all of them. There seems to be a workaround for it -- not using `SynchronizeFlags.All`, and instead using all other flags with a bitwise OR between them, except the `SynchronizeFlags.ApplyDefaultValuesForMissingNonMandatoryFields`. That is the only solution for me at the moment. The moment I add SynchronizeFlags.ApplyDefaultValuesForMissingNonMandatoryFields, the exception is thrown.

Comment: that's quite weird

Comment: I haven't double-checked it myself, but `SF.All ^ SF.ApplyDefaultValuesForMissingNonMandatoryFields` should give the same result as bitwise OR-ing all other flags.